# How can I open a terminal and run a program in it automatically on my raspberry pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Just like the title says, I would like to turn on my raspberry pi and have it automatically open a terminal and that terminal would automatically start a python script. Preferably in a way where I can run 4 different terminals each running a different .py file.

I have done the rc.local approach but the programs do not open in a terminal and that is essential for the functionality of the code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file found here:
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

add your commands to it
@python PathToScript/script.py

Edit: I realize you want the terminal open. I believe this will work
@lxterminal --command "python pathToScript/script.py"